# Datatables jQuery plugin with Bootstrap 3 nav-tabs class - Ignoring table options on 2nd tab

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm using bootstrap 3 and the datatables jquery plugin to produce multiple tables on different tabs using the nav-tabs class. The trouble I'm having is that the datatable on the second tab seems to be ignoring my spacing that I have set in the options which seems to change again when clicking on different pages of the table! The table on the first tab works perfectly though.

Screenshot of 1st tab:
[image]

2nd tab:
[image]

I'm setting the tables up within the document ready function:

```
    $('#single_group_users_table').dataTable({
        "order": [],
        "columnDefs": [
            { "targets": 0, "width": "5%" },
            { "targets": 1, "width": "10%" },
            { "targets": [2,3], "width": "47.5%" },
            { "targets": 0, "orderable": false }
        ]
    });
    $('#single_group_add_users_table').dataTable({
        "order": [],
        "columnDefs": [
            { "targets": 0, "width": "5%" },
            { "targets": 1, "width": "10%" },
            { "targets": [2,3], "width": "47.5%" },
            { "targets": 0, "orderable": false }
        ]
    });
```

My only thoughts were that I might need to redraw the table once the tab has been clicked on but I'm not sure if that will make a difference here.

Has anyone that has used this plugin with bootstrap got any ideas?

Slightly related query, what way is considered best practice to load these tables? If the site has multiple data tables over multiple pages, can I safety stick everything into one .js within the document load function?

Answer (score 2):

#### SOLUTION

Use [`columns.adjust()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust%28%29) API method to recalculate columns widths.

From the [manual](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust%28%29):

> *Call it when the table becomes visible if hidden when initialized (for example in a tab) or when the data changes significantly.*

```js
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){
   $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
      .columns.adjust();
});
```

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/07zdqksw/) for code and demonstration.

#### LINKS

See [jQuery DataTables – Column width issues with Bootstrap tabs](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs) for solution to the most common problems with jQuery DataTables and Bootstrap Tabs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've been trying the code but I can't seem to get anything from the  'shown.bs.tab' event, I've been testing the following and getting no alerts:

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on( 'shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        alert('test');
    });

Comment: @user2321428, if you use [Bootstrap Tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) properly you should have `<a data-toggle="tab">Tab</a>` elements. Create a jsFiddle with your code and post it so we could help.

Comment: @user2321428, the API method I used required jQuery DataTables 1.10.8 or above, maybe that is why it didn't work for you. I have updated the code to lower the requirement to 1.10.0 and above.